# Jewish Academy Press

Tags: books-generally

Does anyone know of any good Jewish academic presses like Littman?

Comment: Do these count: http://www.upenn.edu/pennpress/series/JCX.html ?

Comment: or what about this http://www.academicstudiespress.com/BookSeries.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yeshiva University Press

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshiva_University_Press